How to fix Swift Protocols?
I have these protocols. First I want a type-safe Identifier that I will use for all Objects as id (as defined by Identifiable).
public struct Identifier<Value>: Hashable, Identifiable {
    public var id: String

    public func add(_ suffix: String) -> Identifier<Value> {
        return Identifier<Value>(rawValue: self.id + "." + suffix)
    }

    public init(rawValue: String) {
        self.id = rawValue
    }

    public func starts(with firstChars: String) -> Bool {
        return id.starts(with: firstChars)
    }

    public func starts(withID firstChars: Identifier<Value>) -> Bool {
        return starts(with: firstChars.id)
    }
}

and now I want to provide a simple CRUD interface for Identifiable objects.
public protocol CRUD {
    associatedtype PersistentClass : Identifiable, Equatable
    typealias PersistentId = Identifier<PersistentClass>
    
    func create (obj: PersistentClass) -> PersistentClass
    func read (id: PersistentId) -> PersistentClass?
    @discardableResult func update (obj: PersistentClass) -> PersistentClass
    func deleteNode (id: PersistentId) -> Bool
}

Now, I want to define a dummy implementatation for testing:
class DummyRepository<PersistentClass: Identifiable & Hashable> : CRUD {
    
    var dictionary:  [PersistentId: PersistentClass] = [:]
    
    func create(obj: PersistentClass) -> PersistentClass {
        dictionary[obj.id] = obj
        return obj
    }
    
    func read(id: PersistentId) -> PersistentClass? {
        return dictionary[id]
    }
    
    func update(obj: PersistentClass) -> PersistentClass {
       return create(obj: obj)
    }
    
    func deleteNode(id: PersistentId) -> Bool{
        if let obj = read(id: id) {
            dictionary[id] = nil
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}

but get tbe error message:
Cannot convert value of type 'PersistentClass.ID' to expected argument type 'Identifier<PersistentClass>' 

at the line of
dictionary[obj.id] = obj

Who knows how to fix this?

It helps to formulate the question. Found the solution whilst formulating. This might help someone.
I needed to change the PersistentId and connect it to the Identifiable definition.
public protocol CRUD {
    associatedtype PersistentClass : Identifiable, Equatable
    associatedtype PersistentId = PersistentClass.ID
    
    func create (obj: PersistentClass) -> PersistentClass
    func read (id: PersistentId) -> PersistentClass?
    @discardableResult func update (obj: PersistentClass) -> PersistentClass
    func deleteNode (id: PersistentId) -> Bool
}

Now I can define a generic DummyRepository:
class DummyRepository<PersistentClass: Identifiable & Hashable> : CRUD {
    
    var dictionary:  [PersistentId: PersistentClass] = [:]
    
    func create(obj: PersistentClass) -> PersistentClass {
        dictionary[obj.id] = obj
        return obj
    }
    
    func read(id: PersistentId) -> PersistentClass? {
        return dictionary[id]
    }
    
    func update(obj: PersistentClass) -> PersistentClass {
       return create(obj: obj)
    }
    
    func deleteNode(id: PersistentId) -> Bool{
        if let obj = read(id: id) {
            dictionary[id] = nil
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    
}

And use it like this. First the specific protocol that is part of the my interface.
public protocol SpecificRepository : CRUD where PersistentClass == SpecificClass {}

And now I can easily implement a test implementation like this:
extension DummyRepository : SpecificRepository where PersistentClass == SpecificClass {}

This solution now works even without referencing the Identiifier<SpecificClass>. Now Identifier is simply a type-save ID that will not allow me to assign an Identifier<A> to an Identifier<B>.
I believe this type safety to be an advantage, because I have another project where all Ids are UUID without any type information, which doesn't allow the compiler to find problems. See as well https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/type-safe-identifiers-in-swift/

You are no longer using the Identifier<Value> struct, and this is fine? Why did you write Identifier<Value> in the first place?

Well spotted! Indeed, the solution  isn't complete. Let me add.
